# PHP sessions for longer period

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

Trying to keep PHP Sessions for 12 hours.

```
<?php

#required files

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 12);
ini_set('session.gc-maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 12 );
session_start();
$_SESSION['site_type'] = "2";

#more codes
?>
```

But the sessions are only for some minutes.

---

**Remember:** Session should be alive even if

- The tab is closed
- The browser is closed
- The browser is cleared from the recent tab (When opening in the mobile browser)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with session can be done with the cookies.

Comment: any success ??? ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cookies to achieve that by save the session array in the cookies and retrieve it when page loaded or save the session data in a database on the server and assign it with key and use that key in Cookie

Answer (score 0):

`session.gc-maxlifetime` is always higher then to `cookie_lifetime`:

After using like:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 43200); // 43200 == 12 hours
ini_set('session.gc-maxlifetime', 100000);
```

After changing this, you can check the values by using:

```
echo phpinfo(); // search both values
```

**Side Note:**

Changing the configuration value by using script always problematical, i suggest you to change values from PHP.ini file as:

```
; 12 hour session cookie
session.cookie_lifetime = 43200
session.gc_maxlifetime = 100000
```

in **PHP.ini**,

`session.cookie_lifetime` always set as 0 which means, session destroyed on browser close.

`session.gc_maxlifetime` is the lifetime in seconds which default value: `1440 = 24 minutes`

Comment: I ran my code + `echo phpinfo();`; And result: **session.cookie_lifetime --> 43200** & **session.gc_maxlifetime -->1440**

Comment: share the result @Bacha, probably GC value keep same, maybe, share the result

Comment: @Bacha: yes, for this i suggest u to change it from php.ini,

Comment: It means 12 hour session cookie is set correctly, then also it doesn't long for 12 hours...

Comment: Any other alternative method of changing it from php.ini?

Comment: Are GC value same?

Comment: no it must be greator then `session.gc_maxlifetime = 100000` use this in php.ini @Bacha

Comment: Ok can you place the codes as my codes by replacing sessions to cookies in php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191453/discussion-between-devpro-and-bacha).

Comment: @Bacha: open your php.ini file
replace session.cookie_lifetime = 0 with session.cookie_lifetime = 43200
and
session.gc_maxlifetime=1440 with session.gc_maxlifetime = 100000
and re start APACHE

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the session duration using ini_set, then you might consider another idea, if you can run PHP version 7 or better you can use this [approach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#example-5996):

```
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0') >= 0) {
      session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 43200,]);
    } else {
      session_start();
    }
  }
```

In this way the session expires only after 12 hours. Hope this helps.